# Mysql tuning/performance for windows

Tags: mysql

We use mysql version 5.0.27 for a desktop application on a windows based environment.
We need a tool (hopefully free) that runs on windows and that can monitor mysql and the queries so that we can hopefully  fix some of the slow queries we have on it and tune its performance.

What would you reccomend? the things i found online where scripts/perl etc that dont fit with our needs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can modify my.cnf and turn on slow query logging. That'll show you immediately what query is causing the slowdown. Also, what table engine are you using also impacts how everything behaves.

Comment: we'd prefer an actual GUI tool

Comment: "the things i found online where scripts/perl etc that dont fit with our needs" / "we'd prefer an actual GUI tool" - get over it. You're going to have to get your hands dirty. See also http://mysqltuner.pl/ , http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/

Comment: Changing MySQL's performance settings trough a GUI tool and not wanting to actually open the my.cnf and read what it says implies you lack knowledge to tune it properly. If you're not willing to input minimal effort - I'm afraid you might even break your MySQL instance, be there GUI tool or not. I suggest you take up the manual and spend some time reading and changing settings manually. I don't know of a tool that lists all of the settings MySQL has and that allows you to change them - have you tried MySQL's official GUI tools perhaps?

Comment: check this out too http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

Comment: @ Michael J.V,@ symcbean Thanks for your comment, BUT, thats not exactly what i mean, we want the GUI tool to diagnose the issues (ie like MS SQL Profiler) to show us where the problem is, not to fix it for us, we know that we have to do it manually in order to fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

That question shouts for the [MySQL Query Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/). This is a simple program that can monitor and analyze the communication between client and server.

It is available for different OS, one of them Windows. It is in its early stages of development, but should be usable for the purpose you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

http://lamp-dev.com/setting-up-mysql-proxy-windows/115

I found above link for getting started with MYSQL-Proxy.
Thanks to Bjoern.