# Recommended MySQL tuning utility for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, iis, performance

I have been using MySQL Tuner (http://mysqltuner.com) on Linux for a while and am quite comfortable with it. Now, for whichever reason, we have had to start hosting other websites on IIS. Is there a similar tuning utility that may recommend config changes to MySQL on Windows Server 2008?

Kind regards

Comment: It's a Perl script, so you should be able to run it on Windows with no problem.

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550344/mysql-tuning-performance-for-windows

Comment: @Mchl: It fails on Windows. It's not written thinking of Windows and it starts by trying to evaluate `$path` to find mysqladmin. It should be easily adjusted by anyone that knows Perl though.

Answer (score 22):

I have just ported the mysqltuner.pl script to Windows - see http://mysqltuner.codeplex.com/. It uses the same checks as version 1.2 of the mysqltuner.pl script, but in a nice, friendly Windows application - no need to install Cygwin or Perl.

Comment: Nice job!  Thanks for the pointer.  This should now be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried this tool using mysql 4.1.9 and got fatal errors using it

Comment: If you could please submit the errors to the Codeplex page, then I  will be able to fix them. You can copy the paste the output of the grid into notepad, or the "New Issue" form on the Codeplex page.

Comment: @PeterChapman Tried to use it, and immediately got "Timeout expired"

Comment: I have posted an updated version, which should fix this bug - see https://mysqltuner.codeplex.com/releases/view/117575

Answer (score 8):

Ok so this is over a year after the question but I thought it relevant because you can actually still use the mysqltuner script if you combine it with Cygwin.

- Install Cygwin
- Make sure Perl is installed
- Additionally I installed the mysql and the mysqld packages as well (Needed for the script to connect to a "remote" MySQL.
- Copy the **mysqltuner.pl** script to your Cygwin user home directory (Found under **cygwin_install_dir/home/your.user**)
- Start the Cygwin terminal
- Run the script **$ perl mysqltuner.pl --host mysql_host_ip --forcemem 512**

If you encounter an error in the line of:
**ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'somename.company.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**

Go to the database server and add the appropriate user and privelages

You should now be able to use **mysqltuner** in a windows environment against local as well as remote MySQL servers.

...screenshots removed because I'm not allowed to use images yet, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of another tool (outside the MySQL Instance Configuration Wizard you can run) like mysqltuner which will not run unfortunately. You can install Perl on Windows, but when run the .pl file you will get an error about $PATH not having mysqladmin in it. Upon reading of the manual *laughing*, it plain as day states there is no Windows support for 1.2.0 version of tool.

You can see if these suggestions help in the interim:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

Edit: I just found this: http://www.webyog.com/webyog/monyogscreenshots
MONyog, it is a paid product, though. I installed the trial and it looks very promising. It monitors your SQL server and gives you alerts and recommendations based on those alerts. Might be worth a look. I cannot vouch for too much other than it has some nice information in just a short period of time.